# Model complete theories of henselian local rings which are not nec valuation rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, model-theory

I just want to ask if anybody as any examples of a first order model complete theorie of henselian local rings which **is not** some theory of valuation rings. More precisely-

I am looking for a theory $T$ of the language of rings such that

1. Every model of $T$ is a henselian local ring
2. There exists a model of $T$ that **is not** a valuation ring
3. $T$ is model complete.

Indeed, does anybody know anything about that model theory of henselian local rings?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are all local henselian rings domains to you? Otherwise, I'd try to find a theory of local henselian rings which are not domains. Unless those don't exist for some reason. :)